# Multiple elements with same class - only insert after last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the JQuery function `.after` function to insert an element after another element.

The page structure looks like this:

```
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

I am using this line of code to insert a `<p>` element:

```
$('.example').after('<p>Hello</p>');
```

The issue is that `<p>Hello</p>` is being inserted after every `<div class="example"></div>` element - I only want it to be inserted after the **last** `<div class="example"></div>` element.

Comment: `$('.example:last').after('<p>Hello</p>');`.

Comment: @unlucky13 Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.example').last().after('<p>Hello</p>');
```